# SceneKit DAE Animation Crop by Frames

Tags: ios, macos, crop, scenekit, caanimation

In my Project I have a `DAE` object that includes all the Animations (as 1 long animation).

I am able to split out the animation using time in seconds with help of this:
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217967/how-to-split-out-multiple-animations-from-collada-file-in-scenekit)

However I want to split the animations using Frames instead of seconds
I have an XML file that defines frames for each animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Anim>
 <Data id="1" name="Bar_COMBAT_mode" startFrame="0f" endFrame="50f" />
 <Data id="2" name="Bar_banging_shield" startFrame="51f" endFrame="71f" />
 <Data id="3" name="Bar_PutWeapon_Back" startFrame="72f" endFrame="112f" />
 <Data id="4" name="Bar_IDLE" startFrame="113f" endFrame="213f" />
 <Data id="5" name="Bar_TookWeaponOut" startFrame="214f" endFrame="254f" />
 <Data id="6" name="Bar_sword_swing_high_right" startFrame="255f" endFrame="295f" />
 <Data id="7" name="Bar_sword_swing_high_straight_down" startFrame="296f" endFrame="331f" />
 <Data id="8" name="Bar_Die_fall_forward" startFrame="332f" endFrame="412f" />
 <Data id="9" name="Bar_walk" startFrame="413f" endFrame="448f" />
 <Data id="10" name="Bar_Combat_walk" startFrame="449f" endFrame="484f" />
 <Data id="11" name="Bar_Combat_walk_B" startFrame="485f" endFrame="520f" />
 <Data id="12" name="Bar_Cautious_walk" startFrame="521f" endFrame="561f" />
</Anim>
```

Is there a way to split the animation in to multiple `CAAnimationGroup`s using the Start and End frames properties of the long Animation?